# Interceptor for Authorization headers using Kendo UI datasource

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I am using webapi and restrict web api's to authenticate by token, so to populate datasource I use request headers in DataSource.

```
var abcDatasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: '/api/exampledata',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken }
        },
    },
    pageSize: 5, 

});
```

the below line of code need to repeat at all datasource

```
headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken }
```

Is it possible to make central function which overwrite the kendo datasoruce headers that provides the token to the request headers? because i have more than 600 datasources, I just want to have token setup in one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can globally set a specific header every time you send a request. Try this one,

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, jqXHR, options) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accesstoken);
});
```

Comment: Working Fine :)